# Dictionary order topology based query

Tags: general-topology

I am not sure i fully understand dictionary order topology...first picture still confusing me, why there is line in upward of a*b , why its jot downward.

and what will be diagram for (2*2,4*5).

[image]

Comment: Essentially: to your last question: to be *greater* than $a \times b$ and also have $x=a$ we need $y > b$ by definition of the lexicographic order.

Comment: thanks sir, i understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the definition of the lexicographic order: the interval is all $x \times y$ with $a \times b < x \times y < c \times d$ (notation following Munkres, under protest..). To be bigger than $a \times b$ is to have $x$-coordinate $>a$ or $=a$ but then $y > b$. But we must also be smaller than $c \times d$ so $x < c$ or $x=c$ and $y < d$. So the vertical lines in between are all point where $a < x < c$.
The points above $a \times b$ are the points with $x=a$ and $y > b$.
The ones on the right are those with $x=c$ and $y < d$.

You can draw the similar picture for $2 \times 2$ and $4 \times 5$ yourself: vertical lines with $2<x<4$, some up-reaching part above $2 \times 2$ and so down-reaching part below $4 \times 5$.  (the left point shifts downwards and the right one upwards; it's really the same).

Comment: hii,thanks a lot, i give myself more than 1 hour for this topic but fail,you clear my doubt thoroughly.